# Onde criar a pasta assets em um projeto android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Onde deve ser criada a pasta *assets*?
Quero utiliza-la para armazenar minhas fontes.

Answer (score 11):

- No Android Studio clique com o botão direito na pasta [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] e navegue até `Assets Folder`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Na próxima tela apenas clique em `Finish`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Isto vai criar a pasta `assets` na raiz principal do seu aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

*Fonte da resposta: [Where to place Assets folder in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio)*

*Não testei a resposta pois não tenho o Android Studio instalado nessa máquina, mas segundo a resposta original essa resposta serve pro Android Studio 1.0 e versões superiores.*

Answer (score 4):

A pasta `assets` deve ser criada na raiz de seu projeto, ou seja, no mesmo diretório das pastas `gen` e `res` por exemplo.

A imagem abaixo exemplifica essa estrutura: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referência: [Google Android 3ª Edição](http://www.novatec.com.br/livros/googleand3/)